# How can I set the innerHTML of cells in a table in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The website I'm trying to create uses a database and I put the values into an array. I made a table with the tds having numberic ids (from 1 to 12) and I want to put the values received from sql query to the corresponding cells.
This is the code that I wrote. Alerting works but not the innerHTML. (It's inside PHP as it gets called if a submit button is set.)

```
$i=1;
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
$bev_temp = $bev[$i-1];
print "alert($bev[0]);";
print "document.getElementById($i).innerHTML = $bev_temp;";
}
print "</script>";
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fill the table with data upon rendering it instead of this JavaScript detour?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
print "document.getElementById($i).innerHTML = '$bev_temp';";
```